# wordpress - wp insert post hook for only new posts saved

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using `wp insert post` as a hook to send an email when ever a new post has been submitted in wordpress, I have taken the reference of this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post) and tried below code. I am able to get emails perfectly, the problem is I am receiving mails even when the post is trashed which is not required. Is there any way to trigger mail only when new post is created and not for any other actions.

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

// If this is a revision, don't send the email.
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

$post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
$subject = 'A post has been updated';

$message = "A post has been updated on your website:\n\n";
$message .= $post->post_title . ": " . $post_url;

// Send email to admin.
wp_mail( 'admin@example.com', $subject, $message );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out just after posting this question, but updating my solution here so that it would be useful for some one.

The solution is I have added a checkpoint by checking the `post_status` of submitted post using the same `wp insert post` like below.

```
$post_status = get_post($post_id)->post_status;

if($post_status == 'pending'){
//send the post pending email
}elseif($post_status == 'publish'){
// send the post published email
}elseif($post_status == 'trash'){
// send the post trashed email
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions). Example for `draft -> publish` below.

```
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'draft_to_publish_actions');
function draft_to_publish_actions($object)
{
//do stuff    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function wcl_insert_car($post_ID, $post, $update) {
    if (get_post_type() != 'car') {
        return;
    }
    $value = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'car_init', true);
    if (empty($value)) {
        // One time code on init Post
        update_post_meta($post_ID, 'car_init', true);
    }
}
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wcl_insert_car', 10, 3);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).